# On error a Symfony application hangs with browser continuously loading the page

Tags: symfony

As it turned out, this problem appears only when there is an error in the code.

A code without errors runs smooth, but as soon as there is even an 'undefined index' error, the whole server hangs, seems falling into sort of an endless loop.

The environment is Windows, Apache 2.4 from ApacheFriends, PHP 5.6, Symfony 2.3

Comment: Do you have example of the controller action for one of the routes that hang? There could be some kind of never ending loop situation going on.

Comment: The code is a working project with several hundred controllers. I just have no idea what code could be relevant. All I have is that log entry.

Comment: You can bypass Apache, by using PHP internal webserver. Just run `php app:console server:run` and open `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: @MassimilianoArione thank you for the suggestion! I tried it and got the same result - so, it is not Apache issue. Going to debug further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a consequence of several issues:

1. Somewhere in the code someone put `ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);`
2. I am working with Doctrine.
3. I happen to process considerable amount of data
4. **Twig, when trying to render an error page, attempts to `var_dump()` a backtrace.**

And when using Doctrine, you know, it's better not to try `var_dump() a query result  (or a back trace which is effectively the same).

After hardcoding values for `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time` using `php_admin_value` I was able to get the long sought error messages in the error log:

> [13-Jul-2016 17:28:32] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1280000000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1245970432 bytes) in \vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Extension\Debug.php on line 66
>
> [13-Jul-2016 17:28:32] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in \vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler.php on line 136

Looks like Twig was choked by the back trace and then Symfony error handler for some reason hanged.

So I just commented out `var_dump()` in a Twig error handler and thus was able to make my system work.

Would like to see a better solution though.